# UPDATE based on Aggregation - T/SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, aggregate-functions

```
CREATE TABLE #Table1 
(
  ID INT Identity (1,1), Col1 varchar(10), 
  Col2 DateTime2(7), Col3 INT, COl4 INT
);

INSERT INTO #Table1 VALUES
('Part1','2014-01-23 22:00:00.0000000', NULL, NULL),
('Part2','2014-01-23 23:00:00.0000000', NULL, NULL),
('Part3','2014-01-23 23:00:00.0000000', NULL, NULL),
('Part3','2014-01-23 23:30:00.0000000', NULL, NULL);

CREATE TABLE #Table2 
(
  ID INT Identity (1,1), C1 varchar(10), C2 varchar(10), 
  C3 bit, C4 Varchar(10), C5 DateTime2(7)
);

INSERT INTO #Table2 VALUES
('One',   'First',   1, 'Part1','2014-01-23 22:00:00.0000000'),
('Two',   'Second',  1, 'Part1','2014-01-23 22:00:00.0000000'),
('Three', 'Third',   0, 'Part1','2014-01-23 22:00:00.0000000'),
('Four',  'Fourth',  1, 'Part2','2014-01-23 23:00:00.0000000'),
('Five',  'Fifth',   0, 'Part2','2014-01-23 23:00:00.0000000'),
('Six',   'Sixth',   1, 'Part3','2014-01-23 23:00:00.0000000'),
('Seven', 'Seventh', 1, 'Part3','2014-01-23 23:00:00.0000000'),
('Eight', 'Eight',   0, 'Part3','2014-01-23 23:30:00.0000000');
```

I want to update `#Table1` based on a match between `#Table1` and `#Table2` on this condition:

```
ON T1.Col1 = T2.C4 AND T1.Col2 = T2.C5
```

And aggregate `T2.C3` values to update value for `T1.Col3` and `T1.Col4` where:

```
T1.Col3 = COUNT(T2.C3 WHERE T2.C3 = 1)
T1.Col4 = COUNT(T2.C3 WHERE T2.C3 = 0)
```

Expected contents of `#Table1` after the update:

```
ID  Col1    Col2               Col3    Col4
--  -----   ----------------   ----   ----
1   Part1   2014-01-23 22:00   2      1
2   Part2   2014-01-23 23:00   1      1
3   Part3   2014-01-23 23:00   2      0
4   Part3   2014-01-23 23:30   0      1
```

My unsuccessful try at an update:

```
UPDATE T1
SET T1.Col3 = SUM(CASE WHEN T2.C3 = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
,T1.Col4 = SUM(CASE WHEN T2.C3 = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM #Table1 T1 INNER JOIN #Table2 T2
    ON T1.Col1 = T2.C4 AND T1.Col2 = T2.C5
```

This fails with:

> Msg 157, Level 15, State 1, Line 33
>   An aggregate may not appear in the set list of an UPDATE statement.

Comment: What version of SQL Server? Thank you very much for table structure, sample data, and desired results.

Comment: 2012 and glad you found my question adequate.

Comment: On a *lot* of questions it is like pulling teeth trying to get these specifics. I asked about version just to tidy up the script a bit.

Comment: Your OP update made me chuckle IRL. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use aggregates in the UPDATE list like that (as the error message showed).

However, you can do it this way:

```
;WITH x(C4,C5,C3Yes,C3No) AS 
(
   SELECT C4, C5, 
    COUNT(CASE WHEN C3 = 1 THEN 1 END),
    COUNT(CASE WHEN C3 = 0 THEN 1 END) 
   FROM #Table2 GROUP BY C4, C5
)
UPDATE t1 SET Col3 = x.C3Yes, Col4 = x.C3No
FROM #Table1 AS t1
INNER JOIN x 
ON x.C4 = t1.Col1 AND x.C5 = t1.Col2;
```

Comment: Ahh, this is a great workaround. Why did you use COUNT instead of SUM btw?

Comment: @user1569220 Simply because with `COUNT()` you don't have to say `ELSE 0`. It already only counts non-`NULL` values, and when all other conditions are false and you leave out `ELSE`, the result of a `CASE` expression is `NULL`.

Comment: Ahh, I saw the NULL and came back to post that...just to find you have already replied. As always, thanks for all your help Aaron. You are really good with T/SQL AND/OR Logical thinking.

Comment: watching your 10 query PASS video on YT right now. :)

Comment: Update, the NOT IN vs NOT EXISTS vs EXCEPT blew my mind...plus some great other tips. Thank you both.